# R: Select only Rows where value greater than a certain value and Mapped to another column where value is Yes or No

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I have a dataframe

```
df:
   Age   Answer
   25      No
   51      No
   45      Yes
   49      Yes
   25      Yes
   60      Yes
```

i want to get the ages of those who are `>= 40` and Answered `Yes`
so

```
df:
   Age
   45
   49
   60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty easy.

```
x = df[df$Answer == "Yes"]
x = df[df$Age >= 40]
x$Age
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset`

```
> subset(df, Age >=40 & Answer == "Yes")
  Age Answer
3  45    Yes
4  49    Yes
6  60    Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dplyr::filter` to filter `Age >= 40` and `Answer == "Yes"` and then select `Age` column with `dplyr::select`:

```
Age <- c(25, 51, 45, 49, 25, 60)
Answer <- c(rep("No", 2), rep("Yes", 4))
df <- data.frame(Age, Answer)

library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(Age >= 40, Answer == "Yes") %>%
  select(Age)

df2

  Age
1  45
2  49
3  60
```